# How to check if a sequence exist in a table

Tags: query

Let's assume I have a table made up of 6 columns, each contains a number. Hence a row of 6 numbers makes a sequence.

Now let's say I have an array made up of 6 numbers. How can I check if some of the array exists in any one of the table sequences? I know how to check if a whole sequence exists but not how to check parts of it.

To check if the whole sequence exist, I can do something like: where ar[0] in (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) and ar[1] in (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) and ... ar[5] in (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6). However, this will tell me if the whole sequence exists or not. But how do I check if a table entry only contains 4 or 5 of the parts of the sequence but not all?

Comment: I've moved your additional information into the question. Please edit the original question directly whenever you have anything to add.

Comment: Which DBMS? Some have native array processing, some don't. Edit the question to give the full product & version. Add the corresponding tag.

Comment: Some sample data and test conditions would help a lot e.g. "when the table contains ... and the array contains .. it returns .. because .."

Comment: Do you have a list of what the sequences should be? If so you could insert them into a table and do an outer join.

Comment: In Postgres you can use the `@>` operator to check if one array is completely contained within another. Or the overlaps operator `&&` to check if two arrays have elements in common. Or the `=` to check  if they are the same. You can also calculate the intersection between two arrays